# command not fount in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to calculate a simple average with this script

```
 for i in 1 2 3 4;
  do
    acum=0
    for n_proc in 1 2 3 4;
        do
          #obtenemos el comienzo
          start="$(date +'%s%3N')"
          mpirun -np $n_proc ./solver_async
          #obtenemos el final
          end="$(date +'%s%3N')"
          #obtenemos la duracion de la ejecucion
          duration=$(($end-$start))
          acum=$(( $acum + $duration ))

          result="$n_proc  $duration"
          #enviamos los datos al fichero result.dat
        done
        avg=$(( $acum / 4 ))
        echo $avg >> result5.dat
  done
```

but it's not working  I haves a syntax error

```
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-8/job_scripts/459539: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-8/job_scripts/459539: line 21: `          acum=(($acum+$duration));'
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-8/job_scripts/459539: line 25: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
/opt/gridengine/default/spool/compute-0-8/job_scripts/459539: line 25: `        done'
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: What does this have to do with command not found?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code, namely `acum=((` is not `acum=$((`

Answer (score 2):

You should substitute the line

```
 acum=$acum + $duration;
```

with

```
 acum=$(( $acum + $duration ))
```

and the line

```
avg=$acum/4
```

with

```
avg=$(( $acum / 4 ))
```

Comment: Bother to mention that `avg` calculated with this method will return just the integer part of the division without decimal points.

Comment: @afs2 please double check your script with my solution; spaces after ```$((``` and before ```))``` are important. The error you get suggests that you introduced a couple of typos.